# Date Restriction-SQL Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this query in my ssis package and I would like to add a constraint where if the data is more than 4 days old to not add it, how would I add that into this?

```
 SELECT PTA,
    Part,
    Duns,
    YearStart AS BlanketYear,
    VIPDoc,
    DID,
    STATUS = CASE 
        WHEN STATUS IS NULL
            THEN 'Eligible'
        ELSE STATUS
        END,
    [PRTCOMACERT STATUS] AS TMSStatus,
    SupplierHTS1 AS HTS,
    PrefCrit,
    Producer,
    NetCost,
    CoCountry AS Country,
    TracedValue,
    Currency,
    MaCountry,
    VEH,
    ENG,
    KitPercent,
    DateCreated,
    DATEDIFF(d, DateCreated, GetDate()) AS AGE
FROM [SourceTempFCA].[dbo].[FCAStatus] g
INNER JOIN [SourceTempFCA].[dbo].[NEW35COMA] t ON g.part = t.PART#PART#
    AND g.duns = t.[PRTCOMASUPPLIER #]
    AND g.yearstart = t.[PRTCOMAEXP DATE  Year]
    AND g.VIPDoc = t.[PRTCOMADOC #]
    --delete from [SourceTempFCA].[dbo].[FCAStatus]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a `SELECT` statement so I'm assuming you mean to filter out those rows? Then just do

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, DateCreated, GetDate()) > 4
```

Comment: yes anything older than 4 days is filtered out, thank you!

Comment: that constraint does mean more than 4 days old correct? wouldn't I need to distinguish the 4 or leaving it like that is fine?

Comment: That should get the ones where age > 4